# binary gets "illegal instruction" on one machine but not another with same docker image

Tags: docker, tensorflow, containers, coredump

I have built a docker image with several packages loaded for a development environment. 
I plan to use the image to make porting the environment to various machines simple.

In a container of the image, I can build my binary (using cmake & g++) on any of the machines I have loaded the docker image to. The binary has executed well within such containers on most machines.

But, on one machine executing the binary in the container results in a core dump with "illegal instruction" reported.

The crash happens on a machine with Intel Xeon CPUs. But it runs fine on another Xeon machine. It also runs fine on an AMD Ryzen machine.

I haven't tried executing the binary outside the container because the environment is so hard to set up.. why I'm using docker.

I just wonder if anyone's seen this happen much and how to start trying to resolve?

If it helps & anyone is familiar it, the base image I pulled from docker hub, to add other packages to, is floopcz/tensorflow_cc:ubuntu-shared. It is a Ubuntu image with the Tensorflow C++ API built for CPU use only (not CUDA).
The binary that's crashing does attempt to open a Tensorflow session before doing anything else.

I'm running Docker 19.03 on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. The image has Ubuntu 18.04 loaded.

Comment: Can you please provide the docker file and how you run it? thanks.

Comment: Hi, thks. I'm not using a docker file, I'm pulling the image with stated repo:tag straight from DockerHub. Then I simply run a /bin/bash container off it and use that as a development environment. I know the image can run Tensorflow .pb model files because I've done it on other machines. Just failing on one. Both Xeon.